# Using LinQ expressions to get Date from a DateTime property

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

In my code I have the following

```
ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "x");
MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(parameter, filterDataField);
```

Which have worked fine until now. But I want to get the date part if the filterDataField is a DateTime property in TSource. E.g. x.Created.Date

Is this possible using LinQ expressions, and linq-to-sql (EntityFramework)?

**Edit**
The code is part of a extension method to IQueryable, I have created a dynamic Where method. It takes the property name (filterDataField), a value and a comparison method (all strings).

This works fine, but I wish to extend the support for DateTime properties, and only work with the Date part of a DateTime field, e.g the x.Created.**Date**.

Comment: Where is your `filterDataField` coming from? What object type is it defined as?

Comment: filterDataField is a string, the name of the property I want to work with.

Comment: Can you add a little more code? This isn't something that I've done before, but I'm sure you could probably use reflection to grab the property. I just need to see what the code is to figure out how to do it.

Comment: @krillgar, I will try to add some more, but the complete code is ~800 lines.

Comment: Just a little bit more around that section should be fine. I'll see what I can do in the meantime. So if you have an object `Person` that has a `string` parameter `Name`, then `filterDataField` will be `"Name"`?

Comment: @krillgar, yes that is correct. I have updated the question with more information, but not more code.

Answer (score 2):

Since I assume that the property named in the variable `filterDataField` is of type `DateTime`, you can just use what you suggested, calling the `Date` property of the `DateTime` structure. Building an expression with that is simply adding another property access expression afterwards:

```
ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "x");
MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(parameter, filterDataField);
MemberExpression dateOnlyProperty = Expression.Property(property, "Date");
```

Note the last line, it only adds a property access to the first property, which in practice results in somewhat like `x => x.DateProperty.Date` instead of `x => x.DateProperty`.

Comment: This is a great and easy solution. I haven't used all of these `Expression` methods before, and is certainly easier to use than reflection if you're already in that space. I'd love to see how this is used.

Comment: I'm using EntityFramework, and linq-to-sql, unfortunately this did not work with linq-to-sql.

Comment: @krillgar It's not the same as reflection, this builds an `Expression` instead of a function. Look at the differences between `Expression<Func<T>>` and `Func<T>`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I was just under the assumption that it was done with the LINQ at that point, and moving on with passing those values to the SQL string. I think I was way off with what the OP was trying to do.

Comment: @Jens-ChristianSkibakk That's bad. The expression itself is correct but most if not all ORMs can barely do anything if the expression is a bit more complex that the most basic ones. In that case, I would suggest just massaging the data client-side instead of hoping an ORM to do something right.